# Question to prove that stone thrown at 80 and 10 degree has same range

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

So , to solve this Q.

Let initial velocity be constant I.e u.

I used the formula of range and let the two angles be $\theta $1 and $\theta$2.

Now , $u^2 $sin2 $\theta_1$ / g = $u^2$ sin 2 $\theta_2 $/ g .

Then , sin 2theta 1 = sin 2 theta 2.

So m theta 1 = theta 2. But it doesn’t solve my Q.

I need an answer like theta 1 + theta 2 = 90 to prove the above Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range of a projectile is given as $R=\frac{u^2\sin 2\theta}{g}$, where $\theta$ is the angle of projection from $x-$ axis and $u$ is the initial velocity.
As $\theta_1=80^o$ and $\theta_2=10^o$, we can see that they are complementary angles ($\theta_1+\theta_2=90^o$).
$R_1=\frac{u^2\sin 2\theta_1}{g}$
$\implies R_1=\frac{u^2\sin (2(90^o-\theta_2))}{g}$
$\implies R_1=\frac{u^2\sin (180^o-2\theta_2)}{g}$
{As $\sin (180^o-\theta)=\sin\theta$}

$\implies R_1=\frac{u^2\sin 2\theta_2}{g}$
Hence, $R_1=R_2$